# Is the Diver able to turn when swimming across a flooded or abyss tile?

Tags: forbidden-island

In the instructions it says the Diver can swim "across" a flooded or abyss tile for one action. Does this means he can make a turn and go to the tile diagonal from his location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, he can turn.**

Page 4 of the rules state

> The Diver may move through one or more adjacent missing and/or flooded tiles for 1 action.

There is a thread on BGG [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/5046828#5046828) where the designer confirms that turns are allowed.